# For what functions is $\lim_{n\to \infty}|f^{(n)}(x)|=0$? (Where $f^{(n)}(x)$ is the $n$th derivative of $f$)

Tags: limits, derivatives, smooth-functions

I recently came across a formula that involved the assumption that $\lim_{n\to \infty}|f^{(n)}(x)|=0$, and at first I thought that it would be true for every function, but then I remembered that trigonometric functions like $\sin(x)$ have cyclical derivatives where after a certain number of times of differentiating $\sin$ you eventually get back to $\sin$ and that there are other functions like ${1 \over x}$ where $\lim_{n\to \infty}|f^{(n)}(x)|=\infty$. I started to think about the situation as $\lim_{n\to\infty}{d^nf \over dx^n}=0$ where $f$ can be found by repeated integration and ends up being equal to $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^nC_kx^k$ which I understand to be any polynomial. But function like $e^x$ have polynomial/series expansions with infinite radii of convergence but $\lim_{n\to \infty}|f^{(n)}(x)|\neq0$. I guess I have to restrict the category of to all finite polynomials for the limit to be true. But another interesting note is that for $a\in(1,e)$ if $f(x)=a^x$ then $\lim_{n\to \infty}|f^{(n)}(x)|=0$ is true, which tells me that it applies to some non-polynomials or alternately to some infinite polynomials.

Even though I've been able find a couple categories of functions were $\lim_{n\to \infty}|f^{(n)}(x)|=0$ is and isn't true I can't seem to find any special classification or underlying similarity for those that it does apply to, so I'm wondering if there is anything that can be said about functions were the limit equals zero in general or if the limit is the only thing that connects them.

As an end note I did a little research and came with one thing that they all have in common, they can be infinitely differentiated, surprise surprise!, which can also be stated as they are all smooth. I couldn't find any subcategorization of smooth functions relevant to my question.

Comment: This question is too broad.  First, polynomials fit the bill, but they are not the only ones.  Another example is any linear combination of functions of the form $\exp(\lambda x)$ with $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ and $|\lambda|<1$.  If $g$ is a function such that all sufficiently high derivatives of $g$ have a universal bound, say, there exists $M(x)>0$ depending on $x$ such that $$\big|g^{(n)}(x)\big|\leq M(x)$$ for all $x$ and for all sufficiently large $n$, then $g(\lambda x)$ satisfies the condition when $|\lambda|<1$.

Comment: I recognize that my question is quite broad. I'm a little confused about the meaning of your comment, are you trying to add to the list of functions were the limit equals zero or are you answering my question?

Comment: I'm giving some idea that the list of functions is probably too large to account for.  And, in some sense, I answer your question a little bit.

Comment: Okay thanks, I guess I'm less looking for a list of functions but instead properties that the functions have in common.

Comment: We also have this: if $g$ is a function such that, for each $x$, $\big|g^{(n)}(x)\big|$ is bounded above by a polynomial in $n$, then $g(\lambda x)$ satisfies the condition when $|\lambda|<1$.  This shows that every function of the form $p(x)\,\exp(\lambda\,x)$, where $p(x)$ is a polynomial and $|\lambda|<1$ satisfies the condition.  I am very certain that there are functions that satisfy your condition, but fail my "polynomial-boundedness" condition.  (Yep, there is: for $-1<\lambda<+1$, $\exp\big(\lambda x+\sqrt[4]{\lambda^2 x^2+1}\big)$.)

Comment: Is this limit uniform of pointwise?

Comment: Mine or Batominovski's?

Comment: Yours. There are many functions where the limit converges for every fixed $x$, but not uniformly.

Comment: Honestly I don't know, I'm not super familiar with the topic or situations where it would matter.